# How to capture video and to save into documents directory of iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to capture video in iphone4 and at completion I want to store in documents directory of iPhone.Please help .I am able to capture video using 
UIImagePickerController but not able to save it into documents directory.

Comment: /private/var/mobile/Applications/B7D80D11-E0C4-47AD-AEF6-9C815AF99CB2/tmp//trim.qx7VMa.MOV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to save videos with a UIImagePicker, you can easily save them to the Photos Album via:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info; {
  NSURL * movieURL = [[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] retain];// Get the URL of where the movie is stored.
  UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([movieURL path], nil, nil, nil);
}
```

This allows you to save it to the Photos Album, and keep a reference path to the movie for use later. I'm not quite sure if this is what you need, but it does allow you to save movies.

**EDIT:** If you really want to save the Movie to documents directory, simply take the above code, and change the line:

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([movieURL path], nil, nil, nil);
```

to

```
NSData * movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL];
```

This will give you the data of the movie, and from there, you can write that data to the documents directory. Hope that helps!

Comment: nop i want to save it to documents directory not to photo album

Comment: This code seems perfect man. I don't really know what the "Documents" directory is on an iPhone, or why you would want to confuse your users and save their vids in an archiac place. But this solutions seems to fit brilliantly.

Comment: Documents directory is editable directory in the iPhone app,you can write files in to it.as I want to save videos only to app which is more secure and user can see by using user name and password

Comment: NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
   
   NSLog(filePath);
  MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
   [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
   moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400); 
   [moviePlayer play];
   [moviePlayer release]

Comment: You need to convert the data back into a movie format as well, otherwise, it's just random bits!

Comment: As far as I can tell, it should be fine without any conversion. I just noticed that you have a [moviePlayer release]; call at the end of your code. Are you sure you want to implement it like that? Maybe try having a global MPMoviePlayerController, setting its frame first, then playing and releasing the controller in the dealloc?

Answer (score 1):

try this it worked for me:

On save action:

```
 NSURL* videoURL = [mMediaInfoDictionary objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
            NSString* videoPath=[videoURL path];
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

call back method

```
- (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can just do if(error). adding the extra != nil is redundant.