# incompatible pointer type nsurl to nsstring

Tags: objective-c

I'm capturing a video clip but I'm trying to save the file to the app documents dir.  I'm getting the following

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURL' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

at videoURL with the NSData line?

```
int timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSURL *videoURL = _movieURL;
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: videoURL];

NSString *videoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.MOV", timestamp];
NSString *videoPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: videoString]; //Add the file name

[videoData writeToFile:videoPath atomically:NO];


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    self.movieURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    // NSLOg("MOVIE URL: %@", _movieURL);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: What's timestamp... whether its file location string or else ??

Comment: [dataWithContentsOfFile:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfFile:) takes a NSString

Answer (score 8, accepted):

videoURL is of NSURL type

```
NSURL *videoURL = _movieURL;
```

So instead of

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: videoURL];
```

try the below code as you have URL instead of string

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: videoURL];
```

Comment: ? you just copied a line of code from the users question. this doesn't fix anything

Comment: Question :getting a "incompatible pointer types sending 'nsurl' to parameter of type 'nsstring *' at videoURL with the NSData line .That means instead of string, there is a URL coming there . So if dataWithContentsOfFile is replaced by  dataWithContentsOfURl, it may solve the issue. Hope this clarifies my answer. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this line inside imagePickerController to save video

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (
                    moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
```

Code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info; {
  // Handle a movie capture
if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

    NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
                UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (
                moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... use NSMutableData instead of NSData

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval interval = [aDate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.mov",(int)interval]];
[vidData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Checkout here u may get an answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970604/how-to-capture-video-and-to-save-into-documents-directory-of-iphone